# Does cupy automatically use cuda and the gpu?

Tags: python, cupy

I know that with other libraries that allow one to use python with the GPU, you have to specify that you're using cuda, otherwise the functions will work but not use cuda, like numba. Is the same true for cupy, or does it automatically use the GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `CuPy` automatically uses `CUDA`.

Before you install `CuPy`, you need to setup your `CUDA` environment. Then, you can install `CuPy` with a specific `CUDA` version as follows:

```sh
pip install cupy-cudaXX
```

where XX corresponds to your `CUDA` version, for example `cupy-cuda90` for `CUDA 9.0`.
See https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html#install-cupy for details.